# I downloaded 12.04 LTS 64 bit at 698 MB but the finished download came in at 732.2 MB

Tags: 12.04

I downloaded 12.04 LTS 64 bit at 698 MB but the finished download came in at 732.2 MB. Is this file corrupted? I tried to verify the file in disk utility but it said there was no checksum to check. I was going to run Ubuntu in a virtualbox as one of my virtual machines but I didn't want to run a compromised ISO. I have an Intel i5 Macbook Pro 8 g RAM. Will this version run in virtualbox on my computer?

Comment: You might want to verify its checksum.https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM

Answer (score 2):

It is OK. The web page calculates as MegaBytes, and 698 MB is for one cd. On the other hand ubuntu calculates the size as MillionBytes and this way 700 MegaBytes is 734 Million Bytes. There is no problem!